# Cassandra as a datasource/producer in kafka

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka

How to integrate cassandra as a producer of data in apache Kafka?

Any specific configuration on kafka config?

Comment: Most options you find will just run C* queries, then serialize it to a Kafka producer... What attempts have you made so far with that? Cassandra cannot push data to Kafka on its own, and similarly, Kafka brokers cannot be configured to know about Cassandra

Comment: I thought there will be any config on kafka to connect data sources.

Answer (score 5):

Cassandra Sink Connector is available at [confluent hub](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-cassandra/) but Cassandra Source connector is not provided by kafka.As of now,Cassandra Source connector is provided by the [landoop](https://docs.lenses.io/2.0/connectors/sink/cassandra.html).

However Kafka provides option to create custom connectors as well.

You need to extend the `SourceConnector` connector class and override its methods.

```
public class CassandraSourceConnector extends SourceConnector {


    @Override
    public Class<? extends Task> getTaskClass() {
      return ImplementationClasName.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Map<String, String> props) {
     // Properties
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
      // Nothing to do since no background monitoring is required
    }
```

You can find complete information at https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html

After creating the cassandra source connector class, you need to configure it also which can be done like [Cassandra Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0-beta-20180702/connect/kafka-connect-cassandra/cassandra_sink_connector.html).

As of now,Landoop Cassandra Source connector is only available for kafka 1.0 and kafka 1.1. I would suggest you to create your own connector. You can also visited this [blog](https://medium.com/walmartlabs/getting-started-with-the-kafka-connect-cassandra-source-e6e06ec72e97) for information.

Hope,it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

For getting data from external systems into Kafka, it's recommended to use Kafka Connect. Kafka Connect is a framework providing a scalable and reliable way of streaming data between Apache Kafka and other data systems.

There are two main types of Kafka connectors, `source` and `sink` connectors. Source connectors pipe data into Kafka from an external system. Sink connectors pipe data out of Kafka and into an external system.

For producing data from Cassandra into Kafka, you'd want to find a Cassandra Source connector. The most popular one is the Cassandra Source connector provided by Landoop, as a part of Lenses, which can be [found here](https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/source/cassandra.html). You'll use KCQL (not to be confused with KSQL) to write your connector query to get the information you want out of Cassandra.

I'd recommend taking a look at this blog post, [Getting started with the Kafka Connect Cassandra Source](https://medium.com/walmartlabs/getting-started-with-the-kafka-connect-cassandra-source-e6e06ec72e97), to set everything up.